# 機械翻訳の投稿への対応

Tags: 討議, 日本語

[この回答](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/29497/15185)は機械翻訳されたものだと思われます。
理由は次の通りです:

- リンクが翻訳されている

  - overview→概要
  - whitepaper→ホワイトペーパー
- 括弧が全角

  - Google翻訳は半角の物を全角にすることが多いです。

これはMarkdownごと翻訳にかけている可能性が高いです。機械翻訳の投稿の修正には限界があります。このような投稿への対処はどうすればいいでしょうか？

Comment: 関連：英語で回答しても構いませんか？（http://meta.ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/1990/）

Answer (score 3, accepted):

基本的に情報を募る場ですので、どのような言語でも回答は歓迎すべきかと思います。
ですが、それが質問者に伝わらなければ意味が無いので下記のような案は如何でしょう？

- 機械翻訳された内容が読み取れる場合
  　→　可能であれば修正する。
- 機械翻訳された原文がある場合
  　→　訳し原文のリンクを記載する
- 参照先も不明で回答が全く読み取れない
  　→　マイナス票

コメントにて原文の提示をしていますが、質問者が日本語話者なので、
あくまでやりとりも日本語で行うべきかと思います。
(今回の場合、まるっと機械翻訳されているので回答者がどの言語を話せるかも不明です)
機械翻訳であると思われる場合や、回答が読み取れない場合は修正を促してもいいかもしれません。

また、質問題は"描画の違い"について尋ねているのに対し、
回答では"機能の違い"について回答されているので微妙に異なる回答と言えます。

私としては質問者や見た人が分かる回答でないと意味がないと考えますので、
読んでわけが分からない、訳しきれない回答については
マイナス票を投票して回答が下がるのを期待する方が良いかと思いました。

Comment: 遅ればせながら。質問について考えてみたのですが、質問の場合、読み取れない場合はクローズ。ということでいいでしょうか？

Comment: そうですね質問の場合はクローズ理由にも「質問内容がはっきりしない」があるのでソレでいいかと思います