# Stack Overflowの英語から日本語に機械翻訳されたコンテンツのサイトについてどう思いますか？

Tags: 討議

A lot of thanks to [@Yuki Inoue](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/754/yuki-inoue) and [@aki](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/14055/aki) for the translation!

---

#### 問題の背景

約1年前に、Stack Overflowの英語からロシア語へ機械翻訳されたコンテンツのサイトがたくさん登場し、ロシア語を話すプログラマーはそのようなサイトの増加に困惑しました。毎月そのようなサイトがデータベースに100万もの翻訳を追加するのです。このようなサイトは数多くあり、今年の春にはこれらのサイトがほぼすべての検索クエリでロシア語の検索結果を支配し始めました。サイト上の機械翻訳は、書かれているもののほとんどは意味を理解できないほど低品質なのです。ロシア語を話すプログラマーの間で多くの不満を引き起こしました。

#### どのようにロシア語版コミュニティは問題に対応していますか？

コミュニティからのいくつかの要望ののちに、私たちは[機械翻訳のサイトの一覧を作成しました](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7104/6)。ロシア語版Stack Overflowでは、これらのサイトへのリンクを含んだ投稿をブロックしています(興味深いことに、 Wikipedia でも同様の手法が採られていて、[コピーサイトへの外部リンクは禁止されています](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Mirrors_and_forks))

多くの開発者にとっても機械翻訳サイトは好ましくなかったので、ついそれらにアクセスしてしまったとき用に、[Stack Overflow(本家) へ自動リダイレクトする拡張機能](https://github.com/Taraflex/Back2stackoverflow)が作成されました。これは、この拡張機能の作成者たちにとっては一つの解でしたが、しかし、多くの人たちにとっては依然これは問題です。ロシア語版 Stack Overflow では、この問題に対して自分たちのコミュニティで何ができるかについての[議論を開始しました](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8371/6)。この問題に対して、我々は良い解決法を見つけられると信じています。

#### 日本語においてこの問題はどうなっていますか？

これが、ロシア語圏のインターネット(Ru-net)で起きていることです。よろしければ、日本語において、本家StackOverflow(英語)に対する機械翻訳サイトについて、何が起きているかの共有をお願いいただけますでしょうか。

- あなた、もしくはあなたの同僚は、これまで本家 StackOverflow の機械翻訳サイトに出くわしたことがありますか？もしそうならば、それはどのような体験でしたか？(もし可能ならば、この質問投稿に対するコメントで、そのようなサイトへのリンクを共有いただけると幸いです)
- あなたは、機械翻訳された投稿について、どう思いますか？ 好ましいと思いますか？それとも問題だと思いますか？
- もし、問題だと思う場合、どのような解決方法があると思いますか？

*あなたの考えをお聞かせください！これはとても重要な議題です!*

Comment: I found an article of lists of auto-translating sites, posted on May 2019. The author blocks all sites from Google search. https://anond.hatelabo.jp/20190529181356

Comment: @nekketsuuu  リンクありがとうございます。 とても面白いです！SOruでは、これらのリンクのいずれかを含む投稿を送信できません。 SOjaで役立つと思いますか？

Comment: 役に立つと思います。できればSOenの対応するQ&Aへのリンクも出せると良いですね。

Answer (score 6):

半年ぐらい前から機械翻訳サイトや（主観的に）低品質な解説サイトに出くわすことが多くなったので、指定したドメインをGoogle検索結果から除外するChrome拡張機能を導入し、そういったサイトを除外するようにしています。

拡張機能の例:

- [Personal Blocklist (by Google)](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/personal-blocklist-by-goo/nolijncfnkgaikbjbdaogikpmpbdcdef)（メンテされておらず、少し前から機能していません）
- [uBlacklist](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ublacklist/pncfbmialoiaghdehhbnbhkkgmjanfhe)
- [Google Search Filter](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-search-filter/eidhkmnbiahhgbgpjpiimdogfidfikgf/)

ユーザー側が行う対策ではありますが、有効な対策の一つだと思います。

根本的？な解決策としては、Googleが機械翻訳サイトのランクを下げてくれると嬉しいのですが。

---

> 多くの開発者にとっても機械翻訳サイトは好ましくなかったので、ついそれらにアクセスしてしまったとき用に、[Stack Overflow(本家) へ自動リダイレクトする拡張機能](https://github.com/Taraflex/Back2stackoverflow)が作成されました。

教えていただきありがとうございます。非常に有用だと思います。上記の拡張機能と併用させていただこうと思います。

Comment: Thank you a lot for the answer (sorry for my English).

Answer (score 4):

> 本家 StackOverflow の機械翻訳サイト

某コードのQ&Aサイトを目にする機会が去年から増えました。
例えば下記はC#カテゴリの先頭にあるトピックを無作為に抽出したものです。

ttps://code.i-harness.com/ja/q/1a5300
ここに記載されているコードをキーワードに検索すると、容易に[StackOverflowの翻訳元](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1725184)がヒットします。

Qiitaの記事で「これ、StackOverflowの機械翻訳を元に再構成したんじゃないの？」と怪しく思う機会は何度かありましたが、実例も証拠も出せないので個人的な印象にとどめます。

> 機械翻訳された投稿について

機械翻訳サイトについて、平凡な日本人技術者(※)の私が抱いている感想は以下の通りです。
※英語力も技術力も凡庸で、さらに質問することが恥ずかしくてなかなかできない程度の能力

- Google検索結果にノイズがあまり増えなければ不便ではないので、機械翻訳サイトにはわりと無関心
- 某コードのQ&AサイトはそもそもUIがイケてなくて不便なので検索上位には出てほしくない

  - でも英語の検索ワードが分からない時に引っかかってくれると、本家を検索するきっかけになって助かることがある
  - 再検索の手間がかかるので、サイトの善悪は別として本家へのリンクは貼って欲しい
- Qiitaは稚拙であっても人力の加工跡が見えるので、心情的に憎くはない(ことが多い)

  - 機械翻訳でアドセンス広告をするだけのサイトは心情的に面白くない
- 投稿を利用規約に反した形で運用しているサイトは論外
- 懸案解決を依頼した後輩が某コードのQ&Aサイトを自慢げに提示してくると、その日は仕事へのモチベーションが**著しく低下**する

サイトではなく投稿については[メタ質問](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2328)が出ています。

> どのような解決方法があると思いますか？

私は法律に疎く、二次利用を禁じる規約等で不便な箝口令が敷かれる結末も好まないので、良い解決方法は思いつきません。
ただあまりに大規模な盗用をしているサイトは、機械翻訳であっても明らかに著作権侵害であるとする判決はないのでしょうか？
法的措置を講ずることは運営会社にとっても負担ですが、権利を守って解決に導く方法の一つとして選択肢に入れても良いのではないかと思います。

私個人の意見としては、議題に上がっているサイトには賛同しかねない点はあります。
しかし「著作権侵害」を良く分からないまま、声高に喧伝して善良な翻訳サイトを疲弊させるマスコミや群衆が出てくる未来も避けたいです。
そしてより良い結果にするために積極的な行動をするほど関心も利害もありません。

非常にセンシティブな議題に対して日和見主義者の回答で汗顔の至りですが、凡庸な技術者の視点はこんな例も多数ではないかと予想しながら回答させていただきました。

Comment: Thank you a lot for the answer!

Comment: I'm glad to hear from your comment. My answer is too long and not easy to read. I hope you to get more excellent answers!(もっと簡潔で優れた回答がありますように！)

Comment: 補足：Stack Exchangeに投稿されたものは[CC BY-SA](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/deed.ja)ライセンス扱いになるので、このライセンスを守る限りは別サイトで翻訳・再投稿しても法的な問題はなさそうです。（それはそれとして、質的に許せるかという問題点には賛同します……）

Comment: 私がよく遭遇するサイトは翻訳元へのリンクがどこかにある（と言っても分かりにくいのですが）のでBYを満たしてると言えなくもないか……と思っていたのですがこの回答に掲載のページはライセンス的にもNGっぽいですよね……

Answer (score 4):

個人的には、そのようなサイトは Google の検索をやりづらくするので、百害あって一理なしなんじゃないか、と思っています。特に、比較的新しい技術について検索していると、比較的容易に、それらのサイトにぶつかるような気がしています。

そのようなサイト上で投稿をみるぐらいならば、オリジナルの投稿を、 chrome の翻訳機能と合わせながら閲覧する方が、多分いろいろやりやすいのではないか、と思っています。

Comment: (Sorry for English) Thank you for the feedback! Could you please tell me what do you usually do if you land on such site from search results? Can we as a community do something to make Japanese speaking developers' experience better? Can Stack Overflow as a company do something to make it better?

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky When I land on those pages, I usually just ignore them.  If my search result is flooded with those pages, I'd usually give up searching by Japanese and start querying by English words.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky Some of those pages, doesn't even affiliate to the original post.  In that sense, those pages can be said to be infringing the CC-by-SA license.  I wonder, if it is possible for the StackExchange, as an organization, to take actions against those pages, to enforce those pages to either at least abide by the license or remove their content.

Answer (score 3):

私が最近、検索サイト経由で目にするのは以下のサイトです。

- stackovernet.com

一見するとStack Exchangeの関連サイトにも見えますが(違いますよね？)、日本語を含むいくつかの言語にSEのコンテンツをその場で翻訳して表示できるだけのようです。

一応は個別の投稿毎に元のSEサイトへのリンクがあること、特に目立った広告があるわけでもないので、悪質性は薄いかもしれませんが、何を目的としたサイトなのかが不明です。

翻訳は読めない程ではないが機械翻訳丸出しの部分もあるので「ありがた迷惑」、フリーワードで検索するしかないなど使い勝手は悪いです。

---

**追記**
以下に記すのは機械翻訳されたコンテンツ**ではありません**が、参考情報として載せてみます。

StackOverflowライクなQAシステムとして [**Askbot** (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Askbot)という仕組みがあり、[ホスティングサービス](https://askbot.com/) を利用するか、[GitHubで公開されているコード](https://github.com/ASKBOT/askbot-devel) を元に独自に運用することも可能で、Fedora ProjectやLibreOfficeなどがこの仕組みを利用しているみたいです。

---

**追記 (その2)**
コメント欄で「ご参考」としてリンクが時々投稿されているのが以下の機械翻訳サイトです。

- codeday.me/jp

一応は出典元(英語版SO)へのリンクが含まれていたり、ヘルプで「著作権は元の著者に帰属する」
と記す一方で、フッタでは勝手に「すべての権利を保有」など説明に一貫性がありません。

Comment: (Sorry for writing in English) Thank you for your feedback! stackovernet does not related to Stack Exchange. It just has machine translated content from different Stack Exchange sites.

Answer (score 2):

- 機械翻訳は完璧ではないので、意味が分からない場合は原文を見たい。
- もっと言うと単語毎に翻訳したりして覚えた単語で次から検索したりする。
- 大抵、外国語が読めない場合はGoogle先生にお願いしてユーザが各自でサイト翻訳する。
- 機械翻訳ならオリジナルの言語ページへリンクが欲しい。
- 検索結果に日本語でヒットしてもらうことより原文の方が大事なので無理に翻訳は必要ない。
- （個人的に）検索文言に日本語を使うことの方が稀。
  (エラー文や命令でリファレンスやフォーラムを検索する)

Comment: (Sorry for English) Thank you for the feedback!