# Stack Overflow英語版の質問(と回答)を和訳することについてどう思いますか？

Tags: 討議, 翻訳

A lot of thanks to [@aki](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/14055/aki) for the translation.

---

英語を母国語としない人は、答えを探すときに2つの知識ベースを使用する傾向があります。1つは日本語でもう1つは英語です。 私たちが英語でのQ&Aを利用するとき、私たち一人一人が何らかの形で英語からの翻訳をしているでしょう。 私はこれが最善であるとは思いません。 同じ作業を複数回行わないようにするためにも、和訳を日本語の知識ベースに手動で追加して、コミュニティーで共有することができます。コミュニティがそのようなイニシアチブが有益であると判断した場合ですが...。

*Stack Overflow英語版からの質問(と回答)を和訳し、それをスタック・オーバーフロー日本語版に追加することについての考えをお聞かせください。*

英語版からの和訳はコミュニティにとってそれほど*有益ではない*と思われる場合、その理由をコミュニティで共有してください。 また、日本語での質問を増やすことは日本語を話すプログラマー仲間がマテリアルをよりよく理解するために有益であると思われる場合は、どうぞあなたの考えをお教えください。

Comment: 関連?: [質問の内容が英語版SOと重複する場合の引用マナー](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/257/19110)

Comment: 確認させてください。今翻訳されるか考えられているのは、質問だけですか？　それとも回答まで含めた投稿すべてですか？　/　Let me confirm one thing. Here which are you thinking about, translation of only a question, or translation of a whole post including a question and answers?

Comment: @nekketsuuu It's about translating both questions and answers.

Answer (score 6):

ウェルカムであるべきと思います。
英語版やその他StackExchange内のサイト内には有用な情報が山のようにあります。[機械翻訳されたコンテンツ](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2905/)が煙たがられるほどに存在しているのもその証拠とも言えます。

[はてなブックマーク - スタック・オーバーフロー](http://b.hatena.ne.jp/entry/s/ja.stackoverflow.com/)をみてみると日本語版が登場した際の「コンテンツが重要」の声が見て取れます。（もちろん質問サイトなので日本語で質問できるのは大事ですし、私としてはその重要性とは別の方向に存在するものと思ってます）

正確性の検証などのnekketsuuuさんの回答にももちろん同意です。

一方で、英語版でUpVoteの多い質問であってもApprovedな回答が最新とは限らない例はよくありますし、仮にその時点では最新の回答であってそれが翻訳転載されたとしても半年後にはそれは古くなっていて英語版には新しい回答がついているなんてことも珍しくないでしょう。現状の日本語版のコミュニティではそういった質問・回答が保守されずに放置される（そもそも気付かれない）可能性も危惧しています。（元質問への誘導を意識せずに用意できるようにしておくことで多少は緩和できるかもしれませんし、それでも日本語しか読もうとしない人には無駄かもしれませんが(?)）
---たとえばSOには承認されていない質問をbotがランダムにageてくれますが、これが有用に機能しているところを見たことがほとんどありません...

Comment: +1: CC-BY SA に則った翻訳の場合、元投稿へのリンクと著作者へのリンクが必須なので元質問へのリンクは必ず入ります。質問の age については、vote が入ってるのはよく見ます。

Comment: ですね。リンクは入るはずなのですが、リンクが単純にあることと誘導することは別問題になるという話です。/voteも確かに存在意義でしたね。ただ承認されない限りはおんなじ質問が何度も上がってくるのが…おっとこれはスレ違いになってしまいますねｗ

Comment: リンクについてはなるほどです。ageについては、Communityによるageは正のvote数になっていれば起こりません。 https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/48578/341401

Comment: なるほど勘違いしていたようですね、ありがとうございます

Answer (score 4):

翻訳は問題ないと考えています。既にいくつかの質問において、英語版の回答を CC-BY SA に則って翻訳し、コミュニティ wiki として投稿しているものがあります。ただ、英語版を絶対として単に翻訳・転載しているのではなく、あくまで投稿者が正確性を検討した上で、日本語版のコンテンツとして新しく投稿しているという印象でした。英語版で vote が多くても、情報が古かったり、日本では使えなかったりするかもしれないからです。過去のメタ投稿[「質問の内容が英語版SOと重複する場合の引用マナー」](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/257/19110)が詳しいです。

私個人としては、自分の疑問が既に英語版で解決されており日本語版に類似質問が無い場合に翻訳・投稿することがあります。こうすることで日本語での検索にひっかかりやすくなりますし、日本語圏で知られている他の知見が集まるかもしれないからです。どちらかというと後者に期待しています。

Comment: Thank you a lot for the feedback!