# 機械翻訳されたコンテンツを含むサイトへのリンクの投稿をブロックすべきですか？

Tags: 討議

翻訳をしてくれた[@nekketsuuu](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/19110/nekketsuuu)に感謝します。

---

日本語版スタック・オーバーフローが成長する中、我々は極めて役に立たない動きに気付きました。英語版Stack Overflowの質問を日本語に機械翻訳しただけのサイトがたくさん生まれているのです。これの何が問題かというと、機械翻訳されたコンテンツは多くの場合単にお互いあまり結びつかない単語の羅列になっているだけで、内容を理解できないということです。

我々は言語の壁を越えた知識を大事にしていますし、人々に必要とされ人々にとって重要な知識を、そしてコミュニティによって支えられた知識を大事に思っています。機械翻訳によってつくられたサイトはそういったものとは正反対です。我々が観察する限り、そういったサイトは人々の価値を生んでおらず、検索結果を汚すのみです。

私は、日本語版スタック・オーバーフローから機械翻訳されたコンテンツを含むサイトへリンクすべきではないと思っています。そういったリンクを含む投稿を投稿時にブロックし、投稿しようとした際に次のようなエラーメッセージを出すべきだと思っています。

> あなたの投稿には、英語版のStack Overflowから機械翻訳された質問を含むサイトへのリンクが含まれています。そのようなサイトは日本語圏のインターネットを使いにくくしています。英語版Stack Overflowにあるオリジナルの質問へのリンクを使うか、リンクを完全に削除してください。

あなたはどう思いますか？　教えてください。

- そのようなサイトをブロックすべきですか？
- もしそうなら、どんなエラーメッセージが良いと思いますか？
- そのようなサイトを知っていてブロックすべきだと思うのであれば、URLのリストを頂けませんか？

Comment: 関連: [Stack Overflowの英語から日本語に機械翻訳されたコンテンツのサイトについてどう思いますか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2905/19110)

Comment: コメント欄で(そうとは知らずに)投稿されるケースも見かけます。[直近での関連するやり取り](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/59904/formdata%e3%81%a7%e3%83%90%e3%82%a4%e3%83%8a%e3%83%aa%e3%82%92post%e3%81%97%e3%81%9f%e3%81%84#comment64650_59904)

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky あなたの提案する「ブロック」は、ブラックリストのURLを含んでいる時は完全に投稿ができない状態を表していますか？もしくは [英語で投稿しようとした時のように](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2838) ワーニングメッセージを表示するだけですか？ / Does your proposed "block" indicate a state where you can't post completely when it contains a blacklist URL? Or do you just want to display a warning message as if you were trying to post in English?

Answer (score 7):

> 機械翻訳されたコンテンツを含むサイトへのリンクの投稿をブロックすべきですか？

たとえ「ライセンス上の問題はないものの、 Stack Overflow の投稿が機械翻訳されただけの低品質なコンテンツ」だとしても、それを参考として挙げることをブロックする必要はないと思います。検索結果に表示されることを煩わしいと感じるならば、それは個々人で対応する範囲の問題ですが、その心情を投稿される内容にまで持ち込むべきではないと考えています。

---

> そのようなサイトは日本語圏のインターネットを使いにくくしています。英語版Stack Overflowにあるオリジナルの質問へのリンクを使うか、リンクを完全に削除してください。

機械翻訳されたコンテンツを含むサイトの具体例として、「[Stack Overrun](https://stackoverrun.com/)」と「[コードログ - コードが世界を変える](https://codeday.me/jp/)」を見てみます。これらのサイトの URL を含むツイートを Twitter で検索すると、これらのサイトを参考にしているユーザーのツイートを見ることが出来ます。

- [url:stackoverrun.com lang:ja - Twitter Search](https://twitter.com/search?f=tweets&q=url%3Astackoverrun.com%20lang%3Aja&src=typd)
- [url:codeday.me lang:ja - Twitter Search](https://twitter.com/search?f=tweets&q=url%3Acodeday.me%20lang%3Aja&src=typd)

検索結果として得られるツイートの数から、これらのサイトの内容が英語版 Stack Overflow の内容だと理解しているかどうかに関わらず、**少なくない人数の利用者が存在する**ことがわかります。もう少し調べると、こういったサイトを批判しているツイートも見つけることが出来ましたが、それなりに利用者がいる以上、コンテンツの低品質を理由にブロックすることは過剰な対応だと感じます。

---

> 機械翻訳されたコンテンツは多くの場合単にお互いあまり結びつかない単語の羅列になっているだけで、内容を理解できないということです。

また、回答文においては、回答者自身ですら内容を理解出来ないサイトのリンクを文中に含める状況や、そうする意図などがあまり考え付きません。そのため、回答において特定サイトへのリンクをブロックする意味があまりないという印象です。そのサイトへのリンクが「問題解決の参考になるかもしれない」という意図で記載されたのであれば、それは回答者に「参考になるかもしれない」と思わせる程度には、文意を汲むことが出来る品質のコンテンツなのではないでしょうか。

質問文についても同様に、特定サイトへのリンクをブロックする意味をあまり感じません。多くの場合、質問文中のリンクは参考にしたサイトを示しています。もしブロック対象のサイトを参考にしていた場合、ブロック対象のサイトのどのページを参考にしたのかや、そのページを用いて何をしたのか、などの**問題解決に有用な情報が質問文から抜けてしまうか、回りくどい方法で示される**ことになります。これは、質問者が問題に対して行った取り組みが、他のユーザーへ正確に伝わらなくなる機会を増やすことになります。

さらに、こういったサイトをブロックすることで、英語が苦手な投稿者にも「機械翻訳されたコンテンツ」の**原文を参照することを強制してしまう**ことにもなります。これに関しては、翻訳ツールの結果と原文を読み比べるなど、工夫次第では大した問題にならないかもしれませんが、英語に抵抗がある人にとっては苦痛を伴う作業です。また、もし「機械翻訳されたコンテンツ」から参照している内容が原文のページで変更されていた場合、本来の投稿の主旨とは関係のない場所が原因で投稿内容が破綻してしまうことも考えられます。

Answer (score 2):

- 質問やコメントにおいては、ブロックしない方が良いと思います。

  - 質問するに至った経緯を弾く理由がありません。
- 回答においては、注意文を出す程度なら良いかもしれません。

  - 機械翻訳サイトの品質が低いことが理由ではありません。

    - 現状の機械翻訳技術では、機械翻訳によるサイトの品質が低いことには同意します。
    - しかし「品質が低い」ことを理由にリンクをブロックすると、じゃあ他のサイトはどうなの？という話になりえます。
    - そのようなサイトにリンクしたことによって回答の品質が低くなっているのであれば、マイナス票を投じたり、コメントや編集で対応するべきです。
  - そのサイトがスパムになっているなら、ブロックしても良いでしょう。

    - しかし私が知る限りは、スパムと断言できるようなサイトはありません。
  - 「可能ならば自分で訳して欲しい」という趣旨の注意文を出すのは意義がありそうです。

    - 英語が分からないユーザーにとっては、機械翻訳であっても多少は意味があるのでしょう。
    - しかしやはり現状の機械翻訳ではなかなか意味がとりづらい日本語になっていることが多い印象です。
    - 回答でそのようなサイトへリンクするよりかは、英語版へリンクしつつ回答の中で概要を和訳する方が、有用な回答をつくるのに便利でしょう。
    - 注意文の例：「リンクされたサイトの中に機械翻訳されたコンテンツを使っただけのサイトがあります。このようなサイトの日本語は意味が分かりづらいことが多いです。可能であれば代わりに原文のサイトへリンクし、あなたの訳を回答に書いてください。」
    - そもそも、回答のコアとなる部分は回答の中に含まれているべきです。

      - リンク先の内容が読めないと解決できないなら、リンクが切れてしまった後に回答の価値が薄れてしまいます。回答を読むだけで解決できるように編集すべきです。
      - このため、リンク先を機械翻訳サイトにするくらいなら英語のサイトにした方が良い、と思っている節があります。
- ただし、今後の技術発展によって機械翻訳の質が充分に上がったのであれば、この限りではありません。

<sub>最初はブロックに賛成していたのですが、よくよく考えるとブロックまですることが妥当な上手い理由が思い浮かばせんでした。この回答は、その上でいくつか考えたことのまとめです。</sub>

Answer (score 0):

機械翻訳サイトと言うと、MSDNの多くのサイトが該当する気がしますが、どうでしょう。 確かに翻訳品質が良くない(最近、特に劣化?)のはわかりますが、ここを外すと、MSDNの多くが該当しそうな気がします。

Comment: この質問の範囲においては、英語版Stack Overflowの内容を機械翻訳しているサイトに限っています。ただ、それ以外の機械翻訳を使っているサイトがどうあるべきかは、確かに注目すべきポイントかもしれません。同じ理由で排除することに繋がりかねませんから。